# What index would speed up my XQuery in X-Hive / Documentum xDB?

Tags: indexing, performance, xquery

I have approx 2500 documents in my test database and searching the xpath `/path/to/@attribute` takes approximately 2.4 seconds.  Doing `distinct-values(/path/to/@attribute)` takes 3.0 seconds.

I've been able to speed up queries on `/path/to[@attribute='value']` to hundreds or tens of milliseconds by adding a Path value index on `/path/to[@attribute<STRING>]` but no index I can think of gets picked up for the more general query.

Anybody know what indexes I should be using?

Comment: Seems weird this question is unanswered.

Comment: `distinct-values` is typically not very optimized, so you need some way to directly access the values in that index, which is implementation-specific. What XQuery processor are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index you propose is the correct one (/path/to[@attribute]), but unfortunately the xDB optimizer currently doesn't recognize this specific case since the 'target node' stored in the index is always an element and not an attribute. If /path/to/@attribute has few results then you can optimize this by slightly modifying your query to this: distinct-values(/path/to[@attribute]/@attribute). With this query the optimizer recognizes that there is an index it can use to get to the 'to' element, but then it still has the access the target document to retrieve the attribute for the @attribute step. This is precisely why it will only benefit cases where there are few hits: each hit will likely access a different data page.

What you also can do is access the keys in the index directly through the API: XhiveIndexIf.getKeys(). This will be very fast, but clearly this is not very user friendly (and should be done by the optimizer instead).

Clearly the optimizer could handle this. I will add it to the bug tracker.